# Error Executing Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am new to this error , it Suddenly came and broke my project .Can any body help me in resolving this error:

> 1. > [ERROR] Error executing Maven. [ERROR] > com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors: > > 1)
>    >         Error injecting: org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven at >
>    >         ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] at ClassRealm[plexus.core, >
>    >         parent: null] while locating org.apache.maven.Maven > > 1 error >
>    >         role: org.apache.maven.Maven roleHint: [ERROR] Caused by: Guice
>    >         provision errors: > > 1) Error injecting:
>    >         org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven at > ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent:
>    >         null] at ClassRealm[plexus.core, > parent: null] while locating
>    >         org.apache.maven.Maven > > 1 error [ERROR] Caused by: Guice
>    >         provision    errors: > > 1) Error injecting:
>    >         org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder > at
>    >         ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] at ClassRealm[plexus.core, >
>    >         parent: null] while locating org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder
>    >     while locating org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven > > 1 error [ERROR] Caused by: Lorg/sonatype/aether/impl/ArtifactResolver; >
>    >         [ERROR]    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.impl.ArtifactResolver

Comment: Please show the pom file. Which version of Maven do you use? That looks like a problem with Maven 3.1 ?

Comment: I was using maven 3.1. Now the problem is resolved by restarting the system only, but i didnot able to figure out why this sudden error comes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error most likely happens because you use a plugin that is incompatible with maven 3.1. Since version 3.1 maven depends on eclipse Aether instead of sonatype Aether - have a look at the [Release Notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.1.0/release-notes.html).

To avoid the bug you should use maven 3.0.5 or update your plugin if possible (see a list of fixed plugins [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound)).